# write.xlsx for genomic data

Tags: bigdata, xlsx, xls

I haveseveral big files contains more than 200000 rows. I have edited them and tried to save them as xls file sing write.xlsx. but I am getting the following error. any suggestion on how to save them as xls file?

```
Error in .jcall(sheet, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row;", "createRow",  :   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)
```

Answer (score 0):

XLS cannot handle more than 64k rows (65535 as the error indicates). Break down your 200k rows into four chunks which then will be less than 65k.

Comment: it works when I break them in several chunks and save them a .xls files. but I need all of them to be reassembled into 1 file. that returns me to the same issue. how I can combine 4 xls files into one?

Comment: I see. Well, it seems clear from the error you posted that the 64k row limit is absolute. That would mean post-processing to combine the rows in a final .xlsx file. VBA, xlwings for Python, crealytics-excel for Spark are some suggestions for tools you could use. If it's infrequent, it can be done manually in Excel too, of course.